# How to change nexus suffix url?

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I need to set nexus to make him change url from one to another e.g if user type: mySite.com/**maven2** he should be redirected to mySite.com/**content/groups/maven2**. How to change nexus settings to do that?

Comment: maby better question is: how to set repository data in two Urls: .../maven2 and .../content/groups/maven2

Comment: The use should only type this information once which is the time to configure his settings.xml so no need for redirection etc. This can be achieved by using a Apache (redirect module).

Comment: Ran into the same problem when transferring from Artifactory to Nexus (don't ask why, not my decision anyway): all build scripts are hard-coded for all repositories urls having the same exact configurable prefix before the fixed repository short name. Repositories groups urls like /content/groups/%name% instead of /content/repositories/%name% is a real problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put a proxy server in front of Nexus that does that for you. I would recommend Apache httpd or NGINX.